# Doctrine where condition for many to one

Tags: doctrine, dql

I have a many to one association mapping where many Exams have one subject
If I have to update marks property of all subject with exam id xxxx 
I use

```
Update namespace/Exam e set e.marks = 4 where e.subject.id = xxxx
```

it is not working 
can you please he
help me to do that in a proper way ?

Comment: What do you want to know? What is your question??

Comment: hi, I updated my answer regarding to your second question. Is that what you meant? If it helped you, you could accept the answer as correct ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not access `e.subject.id` without a join in your query. But a join is not possible in a Doctrine update statement, since its MySQL specific.

What should work is to compare the whole entity:

```
$subject = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('namespace\subject')
    ->find(xxx);

$query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
    ->update('namespace\Exam', 'e') 
    ->set('e.marks', '4')
    ->where('e.subject = :subject')
    ->setParameter('subject', $subject);
```

Or, if you don't want to have another database query and the primary key of your subject entity consists only of one column (e.g. `id`), you could also compare with this primary key:

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
    ->update('namespace\Exam', 'e') 
    ->set('e.marks', '4')
    ->where('e.subject = :id')
    ->setParameter('id', xxx);
```

Also have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15293502/doctrine-query-builder-not-working-with-update-and-inner-join), the user wasn't able to join in his update statement too.

**Edit:** added more general approach

Comment: if the property is not an identity then what should we do ?

Comment: you mean if the primary key consists of more than one column? In that case you can compare with the complete subject object.