# HOW MAKE A update WITH left join DOCTRINE

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

i want to do this in doctrine symonfy2

```
 update producto p
 left join producto_compra pc ON p.id = pc.id_producto
 set p.cantidad = (p.cantidad - pc.cantidad)
 where pc.id_compra = '56';
```

and i tried with this, and it doesnt work

```
$em = $this->getEntityManager();

 $query = $em->createQuery('UPDATE ORM\Entity\Producto p '
 . 'LEFT JOIN ORM\Entity\ProductoCompra pc WITH p.id = pc.idProducto '
 . 'SET p.cantidad = (p.cantidad - pc.cantidad) '
 . 'WHERE pc.idCompra = :fc ')
 ->setParameter('fc', $facturacompra);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

similar question look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15293502/doctrine-query-builder-not-working-with-update-and-inner-join), i see that join is not supported in update or delete queries.